# Problem with basic listener behaviors in Java

Tags: java, swing, listener

It's a little embarassing to not know how to fix this on my own, seeing how I have a bit of experience with Java, however until now I've never really done anything other than web programming with Java.

I'm trying to create a wizard, and trying to generalize creation of the fields presented in the window.  As such, I don't have direct control over the actual component JTextField but a wrapper class which handles the finer details.  However I would like to know when the value has changed, so I've added a "addVetoableChangeListener"  method which allows me to register a VetoableChangeListener to the JTextField itself.

I've verified that the method gets called and that it passes the listener onto the JTextField in debug.  However, nothing gets called.  No exception is launched, and my breakpoint inside the method which implements the interface VetoableChangeListener is never called.

Is there something I'm not getting?  Does the listener have to be some sort of component before it works correctly or does it simply have to implement the interface?  Perhaps I'm overlooking an obvious error because I've been concentrating on it for too long, and I'm hoping it'll be evident to one of you.  A simpler version of what I'm attempting is:

```
    public class TomcatConfigPanel extends WizardKeyValuePanel implements VetoableChangeListener {
       protected void initPanel(JPanel mainPanel) {
          addField("port", "8080");

          IWizardField portField = getField("port");
          portField.addVetoableChangeListener(this);
       }

       public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
             throws PropertyVetoException {
          // Stuff that would drive you Lovecraft insane if you saw what was written here
       }        
    }

   public class WizardTextField implements IWizardField {
      private JLabel label;
      private JTextField field;

      public WizardTextField() {
         // some initialization stuff ...
      }

      public void addVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener listener) {
         field.addVetoableChangeListener(listener);
      }
   }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  It would be important for it to use standard J2SE classes, rather than 3rd party classes such as 'WizardTextField'.

Comment: I'd remove WizardTextField, but then I'd be calling "field.addVetoableChangeListener" directly and you'd call me out for not providing enough information.  For all I know, that's part of the problem.

Comment: If you read the link on the sscce, you'd know that if it doesn't demonstrate the problem, it isn't an sscce.  Please read the link that andrew provides.

Comment: I've eliminated 4 lines of code in total, reducing the amount of code to 26 lines total, including empty lines.  I await your solution, Andrew Thompson.

Comment: @Hovercraft, TomcatConfigPanel isn't standard J2SE either, yet I can't remove it for obvious reasons.  WizardTextField might very well be part of the problem, so I don't think I can remove that either.  If the problem is evident, please indicate where the error lies or probably lies.  Otherwise, I'll come to the conclusion myself that it's something else, though it'd have to be due to some unforeseen behavior like all listeners being removed or something like that.

Comment: @Neil "I await your solution, Andrew Thompson."  Well aren't you just chock full of unrealized expectations!  Good luck with that well developed sense of self entitlement.  I was just offering some general advice about the best strategy for getting answers.  ;) Edit: Advice it seems you did not bother reading.

Comment: @Andrew If you truly wanted me to consider your advice, you'd do more than throw out a link with a condescending tone.  Maybe good for getting votes, but it hardly helped me.  Though fortunately someone took the energy to answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VetoableChangeListener will only be called if a **constrained** property is being changed on the JTextField. A constrained property is a property whose setter method throws a `PropertyVetoException`. So, if your code never calls any such setter method on the JTextField, your listener won't ever be called. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/properties/constrained.html for more details.

I haven't found any constrained property in JTextField (and in all its class hirarchy) in the API doc, so I doubt your listener could ever be called.

Comment: That's lame.  Why would they even have such a listener if it'd never be called?  Thank you for your input.

Comment: The addVetoableChangeListener method is in JComponent : they put it in the base class of all Swing components in order for them to support constrained properties and their associated listeners without much effort. But JTextField doesn't have any. In fact, it seems only JInternalFrame has constraiend properties in the standard swing components.